# How to get custom separators in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server that looks like this

```
Value   First  Last   Email        Phone
-----------------------------------------------------
1       Smith CLEO some@yahoo.com 123456774
```

If this table was in Oracle and I wanted to get all the properties separated by different separators then I would write something like this

```
Select 
Value ||','||
First ||'!'||
Last ||'?'||
Email ||'~'||
Phone
from user_table;
```

I would get output like this

```
1,Smith!CLEO?some@yahoo.com~123456774
```

Notice all the separators are different. How can I write a similar select statement for SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concat()`:

```
Select concat(Value, ',', First , '!', Last, '?', Email, '~', Phone)
from user_table;
```